# Additional fields searchable in Acumatica report parameter selector (similar to FastFilterFields on page selector)

Tags: acumatica

We have a custom table and use a selector on the key field of this table on various pages. In the selector we need the ability to also search on other fields so we set the page entry for PXSelector to include FastFilterFields as shown in this example:

```
<px:PXSelector ID="edMyCustomField" runat="server" AutoRefresh="True" 
    DataField="MyCustomField" DataSourceID="ds" CommitChanges="True">
        <GridProperties FastFilterFields="InventoryID,InventoryItem__Descr">
            <Layout ColumnsMenu="False" />
        </GridProperties>
</px:PXSelector>
```

This works great on our pages. In the example above, entries into the selector search box will return rows with matching values from the MyCustomField, Inventory ID, InventoryItem.Descr fields.

Now the issue/question…

We want the same search/FastFilterFields functionality for our reports on our report parameter selectors. Currently the selector only allows the search on the field tied to the selector (one searchable field).

**How do we enable our report selectors to use additional searchable fields the same as our custom pages?**

Comment: So far from what I am finding... this is not possible unless someone has some other ideas? I know the users can still filter columns in the selector, but the users are use to using the selector search for this very common field in many of our pages - reports selectors on the same field should function the same I would think.

Comment: Have you assigned the source field of the input parameter, to the same field which contains the Selector?  I.e. InventoryItem.inventoryID, not SOLine.inventoryID

Comment: The source field works fine and is searchable in both pages and reports. The question is for the 2nd, 3rd, etc. fields that are not searchable in a report selector as they are in our custom page selectors using FastFilterFields

Comment: So is it possible or have we found any alternate solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have found it is not possible for searching beyond the standard 2 fields in a selector used on a report. By default the only searchable fields are the field being selected and the description field defined as the description field in the select attribute.